# Expected resource of type color error when getting color from a color selector

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm trying to get a color from a selector like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/white" />
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:color="#80FFFFFF" />
</selector>
```

By calling

```
ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.drawable.bottom_navigation_colors_white)
```

But it produces `Expected resource of type color` error which is highlighted as error (highted in red) but but does not prevent from compiling.

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

According to Android developers documentation, `getColorStateList` expects a color resource id. You are passing a drawable resource id.

So you just need to create the selector under the `color` resources folder (instead of `drawable`). Then you will be able to access the resource with `R.color` instead of `R.drawable`

```
ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.bottom_navigation_colors_white)
```